# Reading XML data using Powershell foreach and assign to the values Variables

Tags: xml, powershell

I Am New to PowerShell. With some reference I wrote the some script for my below Scenario.

Suggest me if there is a better way to do this.

I have the following XML Data in a file "Test1.xml":

```xml
<TextValuess>
    <TextValues Name="Value1" Override="true" Type="String">
        <DEV>Source=DEV;Catalog=DEV_DMT;Integrated Security=SSPI;</DEV>
        <INT10>Source=LAB;Catalog=TST_INT10;Integrated Security=SSPI;</INT10>
        <INT>Source=LAB1;Catalog=TST_INT1;Integrated Security=SSPI;</INT>
        <INT2>Source=LAB10;Catalog=TST_INT12;Integrated Security=SSPI;</INT2>
    </TextValues>
    <TextValues Name="ENVIRONMENT" Override="true" Type="String">
        <DEV>DEV</DEV>
        <INT10>INT10</INT10>
        <INT>INT1</INT>
        <INT2>INT15</INT2>
    </TextValues>
</TextValuess>
```

I Was able to read the required data using the below PowerShell script. But I wasn't able to assign the values to PowerShell Variables.

My Powershell script is:

```bsh
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content D:\Roshan\Test1.xml
$child = 'INT10'
$XmlDocument.SelectNodes("//TextValues[./${child}]") | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'Name'  = $_.Name
        'Value' = $_.$child
    }
}
```

I need some inputs/Suggestions how I can pass these XML Values to the Stored Procedure.

```
[xml]$XmlDocument = Get-Content D:\Roshan\Test1.xml
$child = 'INT10'
```

#Commands to connect with SQL Server ( I have done this)

```
$XmlDocument.SelectNodes("//TextValues[./${child}]") | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        $Name  = $_.Name   #Need to Assign Value to a Variable $Name
        $Value = $_.$child

      # I Want to call a stored procedure from XML here. 
    }
}
```

Comment: What operation are you trying to perform with those values, and where? Inside the loop? After the loop? Please elaborate. Also, your sample code is inconsistent (`$Xml` vs. `$XmlDocument`).

Comment: this `$XmlDoc.TextValuess.TextValues[0].Name` will give you the `.Name` value [`Value1`] for the 1st item in the `TextValues` array. then this `$XmlDoc.TextValuess.TextValues[0].INT10` will give you the `.INT10` value [`Source=LAB;Catalog=TST_INT10;Integrated Security=SSPI;`] of that same item.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Sorry for the confusion. I Have updated the Question.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - I Want to connect to a database and Need to call a stored a Procedure to pass these XML values as Parameter to that procedure. I have Created as Sql Connection Before the Loop. I Want to perform the call the procedure Inside the Loop.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - Thank you for the Info. But I Need to loop through all the child tags as it is not constant. I have preferred to use loop.

Comment: @Roshan - ah! that makes sense ... i will go back to lurking! good luck ... [*grin*]

Comment: In your example $name and $value are psobject property names, shouldn't you define them before creating an object?

Comment: Please update your question with a more complete example of what you're trying to do. From what you described here I don't see why you'd even need to create a custom object. Just using `$_.$child` should suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also confused as to why you would need to create variables using the properties you have gathered, but here's something that might work for you then:

```
$child = 'INT10'
[xml]$XmlDocument = @"
<TextValuess>
    <TextValues Name="Value1" Override="true" Type="String">
        <DEV>Source=DEV;Catalog=DEV_DMT;Integrated Security=SSPI;</DEV>
        <INT10>Source=LAB;Catalog=TST_INT10;Integrated Security=SSPI;</INT10>
        <INT>Source=LAB1;Catalog=TST_INT1;Integrated Security=SSPI;</INT>
        <INT2>Source=LAB10;Catalog=TST_INT12;Integrated Security=SSPI;</INT2>
    </TextValues>
    <TextValues Name="ENVIRONMENT" Override="true" Type="String">
        <DEV>DEV</DEV>
        <INT10>INT10</INT10>
        <INT>INT1</INT>
        <INT2>INT15</INT2>
    </TextValues>
</TextValuess>
"@

$result = $XmlDocument.SelectNodes("//TextValues/$child") | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        # I don't know what you want in 'Name'.. Do you mean the 'Name' attribute from the parent node (TextValues) ?
        'ParentName' = $_.ParentNode.Name  # --> "Value1"
        'Name'       = $_.LocalName        # --> "INT10"
        'Value'      = $_.InnerText        # --> "Source=LAB;Catalog=TST_INT10;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    }
}
```

`$result` now is an array with PSObjects:

> ```
> ParentName  Name  Value                                                 
> ----------  ----  -----                                                 
> Value1      INT10 Source=LAB;Catalog=TST_INT10;Integrated Security=SSPI;
> ENVIRONMENT INT10 INT10
> ```

To use the various properties and put them in variables (although you could simply use them as-is..)

```
foreach ($item in $result) {
    $Name = $item.Name    # or $item.ParentName if that is what you are after
    $Value = $item.Value

    # do something with the variables
}
```